# Do most modern kernels use DMA for network IO with generic Ethernet controllers?

Tags: networking, io, kernel

In most modern operating systems like Linux and Windows, is network IO typically accomplished using DMA?  This is concerning generic Ethernet controllers; I'm not asking about things that require special drivers (such as many wireless cards, at least in Linux).  I imagine the answer is "yes," but I'm interested in any sources (esp. for the Linux kernel), as well as resources providing more general information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that there really is such a thing as a *generic* network interface controller, but the nearest thing I know of -- the [NE2000](http://wiki.osdev.org/Ne2000) interface specification, implemented by a large number of cheap controllers -- appears to have at least some limited DMA support, and more sophisticated controllers are likely to include more sophisticated features.

Answer (score 2):

The question should be a bit different:

> Is typical network adapter have dma
>   controller on board ?

After finding answer on this question ( i guess in 99.9% it will be yes), you should ask about specific driver for each card. I assume that any decent driver will fully utilize hardware capabilities (i.e DMA support in our case), but question about OS is not relevant, since no OS can force the driver to implement DMA support. A high level OS like Windows and Linux provide a primitives to easier implementation of DMA, but implementing is responsibility of the driver.